# Find out system requirements for java program?

Tags: java, requirements

I would like to know how to test my program, actually a game. To find out what the person will need hardware wise to play the game. I was kind of hoping there was a way to monitor this on your system so I could see what they would need for particular parts of the game. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a simple way.  You need to find a way to measure meaningful stats about your program like Frames Per Second. Programatically slow down the app and judge what is the slowest yet acceptable performance.  Then you will have to test your app on several different pieces of hardware to find a rough idea of the performance difference and to use to calculate a rough minimum requirement.